# Is there a way to detect not documented REST WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to scan website to detect not documented public/non-public web api methods?

I'm developing a tool where I use non public API, i.e. API protected by public/private key.
I suppose their documentation is not updated well and there are more methods than described in documentation.
I wondered whether it is possible to discover non documented api methods that might already exist.

p.s. I understand consequences of using non-documented api..